# HTML5 audio: Get filetype with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html5-audio

How can I get the file type of the audio src (e.g. "ogg")?

```
$('.html5audio').each(function(index) {
    var $play = $(this),
        file = this.firstChild,
        type = file.attr('src').replace(/\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/g, $1);

    $play.append('(' + type + ')');
});
```

It seems that `file = this.firstChild` doesn't work properly but this is needed to play the file.

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/4jPKH/3/

Comment: There is no `.html5audio` element in that fiddle, and `file` is not a jQuery object, so it has no `attr()` method, and finally, the regex does'nt work?

Comment: You also have an extra `</span>` that doesn't need to be there. Would figure that it being highlighted in red would be a give away.

Comment: Here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4jPKH/5/)

Comment: Sorry for the copy-paste chaos. http://jsfiddle.net/4jPKH/6/

Comment: @Martin -> should look more like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4jPKH/12/)

Comment: Thanks adeneo. `slice(-3)` doesn't fit all (e.g. flac), so `type = file.src.replace(/^.*\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5})$/g, '$1');`

Comment: Object #<HTMLAudioElement> has no method 'attr' it should be file.src

Comment: What about this: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dim13i/4jPKH/9/)?

Comment: Sure, I used slice as it was easy, but splitting or using whatever regex will fit should work fine, like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4jPKH/15/)